# Java Server Context and JNDI missing entries

Tags: java, jndi, java-ee-8

I have an older client/server Swing GUI enterprise java application (j2ee 1.4 version ear) running on AIX OS, with WebSphere 8.5.5.13 as the application server.

Currently, my application runs on Java 7, I am in the process of changing this to Java 8.  My development environment is working on Windows, with IBM RAD 9.6.1, and same version of WAS.  So far, this local configuration environment is working fine locally that I can tell.

For the EAR I have pushed out to the AIX servers, my JNDI seems to be missing quite few entries.  When I attempt to look up a JMS entry for an IBM MQ QUEUE, locally on my dev, the configuration works, the entries are there.  On the remote AIX server, its not in the context when I look it up.

When I look at the JVM log on the Application Server on the remote server, it appears that the entries are being bound successfully.  I am at a loss to understand how this context is apparently not being lost.  I would appreciate any pointers anyone has for where to look for a configuration issue.  Much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes to this, I never figured out WHY this was happening.  What I found out is that the Websphere based IBM Java SDK I had on my server was pretty old.  I had this patched to a newer version by my server admin, and the issue was resolved, and has not come back.  So maybe this WAS SDK was just bad/corrupted, and this issue was fixed in later releases.